# I need to rotate (scroll) images using the galleria module

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-6, jcarousel, galleria

I am using galleria & jCarousel and need to have the slideshow scroll through the images. Does anyone know a simple javascript that I can use for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind I figured it out... with a simple javascript...

```
$(function(){
var slideshow,
    slideshowPause =  5 //seconds 
        $('#slideshow').fadeIn()
        slideshow = window.setInterval(function(){
            $.galleria.next()
    }, slideshowPause * 1000)
});
```

Comment: Always feels good to solve your own problems.  Thanks for posting the code solution.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned, there's nothing better than jQuery Tools Scrollable:

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/index.html